# How to implement a concurrent, thread-safe cache in Java?

Tags: java, caching, concurrency, thread-safety

I'm working on an application where I need to implement a cache that supports concurrent access and provides thread safety. The cache should allow multiple threads to read from it simultaneously while ensuring that write operations are atomic and synchronized.

I have explored the `java.util.concurrent` package and its classes like `ConcurrentHashMap`, but I'm not sure how to design a cache that meets my requirements. I also need to handle cache eviction based on a certain policy (e.g., LRU - Least Recently Used).

Could anyone provide guidance or a code example demonstrating how to implement a concurrent, thread-safe cache in Java? Specifically, I'm interested in strategies for handling read/write synchronization, managing cache entries, and implementing the eviction policy.

I appreciate any help or insights you can provide. Thank you!

In my attempts to implement a concurrent, thread-safe cache in Java, I initially explored using the 'java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap' class. My expectation was that by using this class, I would have a basic concurrent cache that would handle simultaneous reads and writes safely.
Here's an example of what I tried:
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class ConcurrentCache<K, V> {
private ConcurrentHashMap<K, V> cache;

```
public ConcurrentCache() {
    cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
}

public V get(K key) {
    return cache.get(key);
}

public void put(K key, V value) {
    cache.put(key, value);
}
```

}

I realized that the ConcurrentHashMap only provides basic thread safety for individual operations. It does not offer atomicity or synchronization guarantees for compound operations like cache eviction based on a specific policy (e.g., LRU).

As a result, I need guidance on designing a more advanced cache implementation that satisfies the concurrent access requirements and supports custom eviction policies.

If anyone has experience with implementing a concurrent cache in Java or suggestions on how to achieve thread safety while incorporating an eviction policy, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Thank you!

Comment: See [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine). A high level overview of its concurrency model is in this [article](http://highscalability.com/blog/2016/1/25/design-of-a-modern-cache.html) and [slides](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1NlDxyXsUG1qlVHMl4vsUUBQfAJ2c2NsFPNPr2qymIBs).